# Add OpenGL effects to video and export as MP4 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm looking to take videos from the user's gallery, allow the user to add effects to the video, and when they're done editing, I want to save the file to the SD card.

I tried a few samples by using GLSurfaceView, but haven't figured out how to save it to an MP4 file. Using the sample linked below, I've managed to get the video to render with an effect to a GLSurfaceView, but I don't know how to get it to then render to a file. I've seen samples that save from a Surface created by MediaCodec, but not sure how to get the video to render to that Surface.

Other info: I'm aiming to support Android 5.0+, but ideally 4.4+. I'd also like the resulting MP4 to be 720p at 30 FPS, and audio doesn't matter as it's getting replaced with an external audio track.

Here's the [sample](https://www.virag.si/2014/03/rendering-video-with-opengl-on-android/) mentioned above. I'm not married to that solution, just looking for what's easy to implement and preferably not terribly slow.

I didn't post my actual code because right now it's just the sample, but I can post it if anyone thinks it might be useful.

Thanks in advance for any insight or advice that can be offered.

Comment: There are examples for recording video frames rendered to a surface, (whether that be on screen or offsecreen surface is entirely up to you.) Check out these links on doing that and they should be pretty easily combined with that example above that you linked to. : http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/